# Is there ways to be fold by using pre-defined strings?

Tags: string, vim, folding, predefined-variables

I like to use vim to program c and c++, but I am disappointed to use the folding scheme, because I have a lot of definition in C.

Such as

```
CONFIG_A_DEFINEDED
CONFIG_B_DEFINEDED
CONFIG_C_DEFINEDED
```

For example:

```
#if config_a_defineded
..
#endif

#if config_b_defineded
..
#endif

...
```

My question is: Are there ways for folding in vim to use sting predefined in files or something like that? Suggestions or any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You need to fold some block of code?

Answer (score 0):

Create a file ~/.vim/after/syntax/c.vim and put into it:

```
if !exists("c_no_ifdef_fold")
  syn region cPreIfdefRegion start="^\s*\(%:\|#\)\s*\(if\|ifdef\|ifndef\|elif\)\>" end="^\s*\(%:\|#\)\s*\(else\|endif\)\>" fold transparent
endif
```

When loading a c syntax file, set your foldmethod to syntax. Use the variable c_no_ifdef_fold to disable this behaviour.

Read the help at `:h ft-c-syntax` and also `:h after-directory` for details.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. But My aim is to fold out selectively in predefined file or some place. Unfortunately all `#ifdef..#endif` are folded. so sad..

Comment: @kevinpark Then you need to write a custom foldexpr. It's not hard. Read `:h fold-expr` it has many examples